# Z-Score to compare data with different time periods?

Tags: survey, standardization, z-score

I have survey data for multiple countries, with respondents nested in countries. The survey was conducted in different waves, but not all countries participated in all waves. Thus, there are countries that participated in Wave 1-7, but also countries that only participated in Wave 2, 3, and 4 etc.

I now want to visualize the changing value of one question (dummy variable: Yes/No) over time; i.e. compare the average in the first wave of participation to the last wave of participation per country.

Given the unequal time periods, does it make sense to standardize the data by using Z-scores and then plot the change (Z-score of average value from first participated wave - Z-score of average value from last participated wave)? Additional info: The data is right skewed.

How else would I account for the different time periods, if I want to visualize the change of answers to the question per country?

Thanks in advance!